# VS2015: Quick way to switch from diff to original file

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Recently we switched to Git and use the integrated Git environment of Visual Studio 2015.

If you view changes to a file via the team explorer, it starts comparing the modified one with the original version. When you're viewing changes in history, you can't modify the file in the diff of course. However, we don't really have a good way of switching to the original file. We discovered setting a breakpoint works sometimes... But mostly we have to close the file opened for comparison and then navigate to the original file. I really have the feeling I'm overlooking something.

So, is there a quick way to switch from the file diff of Visual Studio to the original file being diffed?

PS: I don't know if it's relevant but we're using Resharper.

PPS: I'm using Jetbrains Rider for a few years now where I can just press F4 and it opens the original file and places the cursor at the right place as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to navigate to the file in solution explorer then hit enter to open the file you were diffing.

Comment: Using 'Ctrl + Alt + L' only makes the solution explorer active in my environment. Which command do you call with that shortcut?

Comment: ReSharper.ReSharper_LocateInSolutionOrAssemblyExplorer

Comment: Ah ok, for some reason the shortcut I have assigned to that command is Shift + Alt + L. But it works, thanks!

Comment: My bad, I of course ment `shit + alt + L`, sorry about the confusion, updated my answer.

Comment: The `shit` key? My `Shift` key is a bit brown and sticky (melted chocolate probably) does that count? ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Sorry if IDE is not relevant, but for someone it still could be helpful*

I'm using `Visual Studio 2022` and this combination works for me:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open `Solution Explorer` on respective file
2. <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the file